# How to set the height of asp.net ListBox control

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

How to set the height of an asp.net's Listbox control dynamically equal to the height of the table cell in which it is present. Or is there any way to d ock the listbox control inside a table cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can:

- Set width and height for table. Then use CSS to set width and height (100%) for listbox control.
- Use javascript to get width and height of table and set to listbox.
- Set value to listbox control in codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

try doing something like that, declaratively:

```
Height="100%"
```

or in the code behind:

```
myListBox.Height = Unit.Percentage(100);
```

Comment: It is not working for me the size of listbox is not getting changed automatically when the the size of the table gets changed due to the dynamic addition of other controls in the table. Anyway thans fo rthe suggestion